# Is there any way, no manually, to prefix prismjs class names because it conflitant with front-end frameworks?

Tags: css

Just starting using [Bulma](http://bulma.io) front end framework, everything is going good until try to use [prismjs](http://prismjs.com/) and start getting conflit with styles because prismjs do not prefix their classes name.

The main problem are with:

```
.number { ... }
```

and

```
.tag {...}
```

It can be override manually but it is not a good practice. This names are too generic or common to not be prefixed by prismjs.

Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Manually fixed with:

```
pre code [class~=token]{
  font:inherit;
  background: inherit;
}
```

Because "token" class name is from prismjs and appear with other prismjs classes, use this selector to help override the styles needed. Just add this to the custom style and make sure to link after any framework css file linked in the html document.